# "Double" function with C++0x

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11

Lets say I have the following simple Vector class:

```
template <class N>
class Vector<N>
{
public:
  std::array<int, N> a;
};
```

My first attempt at `double` is the following:

```
template <class N>
Vector<N>&& double1(Vector<N>&& x) 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i != N, ++i) { x.a[i] *= 2; }
  return static_cast<Vector<N>&&>(x);
}
```

This looks ok initially, but if I do:

```
auto x&& = double1(makeVector(1,2,3))
```

I'll have references to temporary issues.

My second attempt is the following:

```
template <class N>
Vector<N> double2(Vector<N>&& x) 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i != N, ++i) { x.a[i] *= 2; }
  return x;
}
```

Which seems not to have the above reference to temporary issue, but does what I think is an unnecessary move/copy on return.

I could avoid both the reference to temporary issues and extra moves/copies by doing the following:

```
template <class N>
void double3(Vector<N>& x) 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i != N, ++i) { x.a[i] *= 2; }
}
```

But then I have to make changes to the argument, which I think is a bit messy. I'll also have to name the temporaries.

My final idea was the following:

```
template <class N>
Vector<N> double4(Vector<N> x) 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i != N, ++i) { x.a[i] *= 2; }
  return x;
}
```

Which would avoid all copies if the parameter was stored in the same place as the result, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Basically I'm looking for a double function that has the following properties:

(1) No references to temporary issues when assigned with auto.
(2) No copies when passed a temporary.
(3) Doesn't modify argument when passed a non-temporary.

Anyone have any idea how to put these three things together?

**Edit**

Perhaps to put things more simply, this is the behaviour I want.

(1) If the argument is a temporary, modify it in place.
(2) Otherwise, make a copy.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. You can't make it not make copies when passed a temporary and still use the result. You also can't make it not modify the argument when passed a non-temporary and also make it not make copies.

Comment: Don't write functions that return rvalue references. What's wrong with a plain old reference? Why is it "messy" to change the argument when in your first attempt you were actually prepared to have to `move` your argument and then reassign it to another variable?

Comment: Also, what's the point of any of this, your class doesn't contain any sort of resource handlers that would even benefit from move semantics.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to essentially rename `std::array` to `Vector`, especially considering we already have `std::vector`...

Comment: Your "put things more simply" seems reversed. Why would you want to modify a temporary in place and otherwise make a copy?

Comment: @Darren: Those are different things. `vector<T>` manages dynamic memory, `array<T,N>` does not - it's an automatic array of compile-time constant size. (Which is why it's all the more unnecessary to write any special constructors for it.)

Comment: @Kerek: Yeah, I get the differences - I'm just saying it's maybe not the greatest naming strategy - next we could have a class called `Array` that actually just holds `std::vector`... ;)

Comment: @Seth: I don't see any reason to copy the temporary. Might as well use it as otherwise it's going to go away. I don't see why double(double(double(make_my_vector(1,2,3)))) should make heaps of copies (or moves, which in this case are just like copies anyway).

Comment: @Darren: We should probably call it `ArrayList`, implement it as a linked list of boost.any's, and force the user to cast the contents back to the desired type themselves. Sounds messy you say? I have plans for another project that I will call the *Litter Gatherer* which will make this better than any container you've seen in C\C++.

Comment: @Clinton: Have you enabled optimizations and checked whether all these copies actually get made?

Answer (score 2):

Your final idea is correct and efficient, go with it:

```
template <class N>
Vector<N> double4(Vector<N> x) 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i != N, ++i) { x[i] *= 2; }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that efficient. Or correct, since `std::array` has _two_ template parameters, not one. So `Vector<N>` doesn't make sense. And you seem to be doing a lot of copying needlessly, since `std::array`s data cannot be moved.

Comment: @Nicol : It doesn't matter how many template parameters `std::array<>` has -- the declaration of `Vector<>` only has one template parameter. As far as needless copying goes, this answer is the correct one _in general_, if not for `std::array<>`.

Comment: @Nicol: there will be exactly one call to the copy constructor (unless the compiler is too stupid to construct `x` in the place the function returns). How is that a lot of needless copying?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I recall something about copy elision not being able to work if the object in question is a parameter to the function. I'm not entirely certain about it though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: If Vector is a temporary, why the need for any copy. The data already exists, it just needs to be doubled. Why copy and then destroy it?

Answer (score 1):

This code does not make sense.

First, std::array takes two template parameters: a type and a size. Second, std::array is an aggregate; it isn't really moveable. The contents can be moved, but not the object itself.

Third, you're abusing r-value references to no apparent gain. If you want to double something, just use a regular reference just like you would have before C++0x.

> But then I have to make changes to the argument, which I think is a bit messy. I'll also have to name the temporaries.

There is nothing wrong with having to actually store objects. Not everything needs to be a temporary. You gain absolutely no efficiency by trying to push a temporary though a function call, if for no other reason than that C++ doesn't allow it.

And there's nothing "messy" about changing a parameter; C++ is not a functional language.

Oh, and r-value references are not "references to temporaries." They *can* reference temporaries, but that's not the only thing they do.